# Selenium IDE click on link identified by text title

Tags: selenium, ide

I am trying to click on a link (TransID) which can be found using the project title. I won’t know the ID#, just its prefix. There are multiple rows in the table that all have the same prefix so I want to specifically click on the link that matches the text from the project title as that is my only unique way to identify.

Header:  TransID, Process Type, Action Item, ID#, IN, Sname, Project Title, etc..

Action:  Click on TransID where Project title contains text…
Tried & failed:
//span[contains(text(),'PRL123456')]/../preceding-sibling:://a[contains(text(),'PR')]

```
  <tbody>
  <tr>…</tr>
  <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
    <td class=" u-tL" headers="TRANS_ID">
       <a href="f?p=pagelocation data">PRXXXXXX </a></td>
    <td class=" u-tL" headers="PROCESS_TYPE">Process - New</td>
    <td class=" u-tL" headers="ACTION_ITEM">Prepare Form</td>
    <td class=" u-tR" headers="ID_NUMBER"> <a href="f?p=pagelocation  data,">100700</a></td>
    <td class=" u-tL" headers="IN">Investigator </td>
    <td class=" u-tL" headers="Sname">Sname </td>
    <td class=" u-tL" headers="PROJECT_TITLE">
        <span title="PRL123456 – My project title"> PRL123456 – My project title </span></td>
    <td class=" u-tL" headers="ASSIGNED_NO_OF_DAYS">0</td>
    <td class=" u-tL" headers="OPEN_DAYS">0</td>
    <td class=" u-tL" headers="FULL_STATUS_NAME">In Progress</td>
    <td class=" u-tL" headers="sort_flag_img">…</td>
    <td class=" u-tL" headers="C45130925951929411">-</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this xpath:

**//table//span[contains(.,' PRL123456')]/../..//td[@headers='TRANS_ID']/a**

This XPath should solve your issue.Let me know if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath:

```
.//span[contains(text(), 'PRL123456')]/parent::td/parent::tr/td[@headers='TRANS_ID']/a
```

---

Explanation:

- `.//span[contains(text(), 'PRL123456')]` - find `<span>` with text containing `'PRL123456'`
- `/parent::td` - find parent `<td>`
- `/parent::tr` - find parent `<tr>`
- `td[@headers='TRANS_ID']` - find `<td>` where `headers` attribute equals `'TRANS_ID'`
- `/a` - find child `<a>`

Comment: I am able to find both elements separately, it's when I try to locate the trans_id in the same row as the given text - that's when it fails. So the given xpath //td[@headers='TRANS_ID']/a will just select the first result whether it is the correct one or not. I would like to select only if the project title matches which is why I was trying to use //span[contains(text(),'PRL123456')]/../preceding-sibling:://a[contains(text(),'PR')]. I will use a variable to capture the PRL in the project title and I want to click on the PR link in the same row.

Comment: Updated my solution, I like being more verbose when I construct my XPaths. Having descriptive selectors, such as `parent`, helps when I revisit an XPath after a couple of months :).